# App for text and image pop-up

Tags: linux

Does anyone know any application for Linux which is simply for popping-up images and text on the screen, whereas interval/duration/position of the images/text are customizable?

Comment: Do you mean over the top of what else is going on with the screen, or a permanent slideshow - in other words, is the "popup" a real requirement, and if so what it on the screen when no popup would be showing?

Comment: Yep - "over the top of what else is going on with the screen". E.g. you're doing your normal stuff, working etc., and then a text/image appears on the screen.

Comment: Maybe `notify-send` is what you're after.

Comment: Yes. That's almost what I need if I only could customize that thing.
Say make the icon bigger and randomize the location of the popup. I followed some tips on creating a ${HOME}/.notify.osd but it seems that the application ignores that file and my customizations in it. Do you know how to overcome that problem?